# ffmpeg how to attach & extract text/data file to audio or video stream?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, text-files, attachment

I have:

1/ AUDIO.m4a stream

2/ a cover album jpeg

3/ an UTF8 text file

I wish to bind all of them into a mkv/mp4 container.

To bind the audio & image I can

ffmpeg -y -i "AUDIO.mp4" -attach COVER.jpg  -metadata:s mimetype="image/jpeg" -c:a copy "AUDIO_COPY_WITH_COVER.mka"

Further to bind the text file

ffmpeg -y -i "AUDIO_COPY_WITH_COVER.mka" -c copy -attach "TEXT.txt" -metadata:s:2 mimetype=application/octet-stream "AUDIO_JPEG_TEXT.mkv"

If I check I get:

> Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'AUDIO_JPEG_TEXT.mkv':
> Metadata:
> MINOR_VERSION   : 512
> COMPATIBLE_BRANDS: M4A isomiso2
> MAJOR_BRAND     : M4A
> ENCODER         : Lavf58.45.100
> Duration: 00:36:10.36, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 67 kb/s
> Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (Baseline), yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 320x240 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 1k tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
> Metadata:
> FILENAME        : COVER.jpg
> MIMETYPE        : image/jpeg
> DURATION        : 00:00:00.000000000
> Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (HE-AAC), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
> Metadata:
> HANDLER_NAME    : SoundHandler
> MIMETYPE        : image/jpeg
> DURATION        : 00:36:10.358000000
> Stream #0:2: Attachment: none
> Metadata:
> filename        : TEXT.txt
> mimetype        : application/octet-stream

**Question:**

**1/ How do I extract my text file?**

```
ffmpeg -i "AUDIO_JPEG_TEXT.mkv" -map 0:t -metadata:s:2 mimetype=application/octet-stream "my text.txt"
```

I get the error:
Unable to find a suitable output format for 'my text.txt'
my text.txt: Invalid argument

**2/If I replace the command with **

ffmpeg -y -i "AUDIO_COPY_WITH_COVER.mka" -c copy -attach "TEXT.txt" -metadata:t:2 mimetype=application/octet-stream "AUDIO_JPEG_TEXT.mkv"

Excuting
ffmpeg -i "AUDIO_JPEG_TEXT.mkv"

get error

EBML header parsing failed
AUDIO_JPEG_TEXT.mkv: Invalid data found when processing input

2/ How can I write in one command the 3 attachments(audio,img,document)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To attach in one command,

`ffmpeg -y -i "AUDIO.mp4" -attach COVER.jpg -metadata:s:1 mimetype="image/jpeg" -attach "TEXT.txt" -metadata:s:2 mimetype=application/octet-stream -c copy "AUDIO_JPEG_TEXT.mkv"`

To extract text,

```
ffmpeg -dump_attachment:t:0 out.txt -i AUDIO_JPEG_TEXT.mkv
```